# Trouble with Java String Input Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm new to Java, and am confused with arrays. Would appreciate some help.

I want the user to input the amount of words they'd like to input, then input those words, and then the words are outputted but if there is a duplicate letter in the String the letter, all of that letter is removed from that word.

This is the confusing and broke program I've made so far...

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    int number;
    String test;
    System.out.println ("How many words would you like to make?");
    number = In.getInt ();


    System.out.println ("Test string input");

    for (int a=0; a < number; a++) {
        test = In.getString ();
    }

    String[] words;

    words = new String[] {test};

    for (int i=0; i < number; i++) {
        System.out.println("number is " + i);
    }

    System.out.println(words[0]);
    }
}
```

Expected Input: 
Apple,
Banana,
Watch

Expected Output:
Ale,
B,
Watch

I have not learned Scanner or BufferedReader yet, and have to use In.get, sorry to those who provided help with these, forgot to mention.

In.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;

public class In
{
  static InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
  static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);

  // Read a String from standard system input
  public static String getString()
  {
    try
    {
      return br.readLine();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      return "";
    }
  }

  // Read a Number as a String from standard system input
  // Return the Number
  public static Number getNumber()
  {
    String numberString = getString();
    try
    {
      numberString = numberString.trim().toUpperCase();
      return NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(numberString );
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      // If any exception occurs, just return zero
      return new Integer(0);
    }
  }

  // Read an int from standard system input
  public static int getInt ()
  {
    return getNumber().intValue();
  }

  // Read a long from standard system input
  public static long getLong ()
  {
    return getNumber().longValue();
  }

  // Read a float from standard system input
  public static float getFloat ()
  {
    return getNumber().floatValue();
  }

  // Read a double from standard system input
  public static double getDouble ()
  {
    return getNumber().doubleValue();
  }

  // Read a char from standard system input
  public static char getChar ()
  {
    String s = getString();
    if (s.length() >= 1)
      return s.charAt(0);
    else
      return '\n';
  }

}
```

Comment: please share a expected output or any error log if you are getting one.

Comment: Use [edit] option to provide more information relevant to your question. Don't make people willing to help you search for it in comments.

Comment: @Pshemo Sorry, I wasn't sure what other information to provide.

Comment: You should combine declarations (e.g. `String[] words;`) and assignments (e.g. `words = new String[] {test};`) into on (e.g. `String[] words = new String[] {test};`) wherever possible. Splitting them up just adds visual clutter. In this case, you can just say: `String[] words = {test};`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Alexander